# 4 bulb Ballast only lighting 2 bulbs

Tags: lighting, ballast, electronic-ballast

I have a six T8 Fluorescent light fixture. The 2 inner bulbs are powered by a 2 bulb ballast GE232-120RES-DIY, and the 4 outer bulbs, 2 on each side are powered by a 4 bulb ballast GE432-120RES-DIY. 2 of the bulbs from the outer bulbs only light up a drop. I can see power going through but not enough to light it up.
What can the issue be? I checked the wiring and the sockets, they seem good.
What else should I look for?

Edit: Both ballasts are new and all bulbs are new. I tried swapping the bulbs to see if there is a issue with the bulbs. It doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the bulbs? Or just to swap the working two with non-working? This test will show you if the problem is in a bulb or in the ballast.

Comment: Yes. I bought 6 new bulbs and the ballasts are both brand new. I tried swapping the bulbs also.